# Getting y value of a curve given an x value

Tags: python, matplotlib

Given a `Line2D` object, which is the output of `pyplot`'s `plot` function, I wish to determine the `y` coordinate of a given `x`. For example, if

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([1.0, 4.0, 9.0, 16.0])
y = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0])
line = plt.plot(x, y)[0]
```

then

```
def get_y(line, x):
    ...

## This should print something close to 2.0
print get_y(line, 2) ** 2
```

I tried using `path = line.get_path()`, and then interpolate but things haven't worked as I have expected. I thought there must be a standard way of doing that...

Comment: Are you asking for a linear interpolation of y-value between two (x,y) coordinates? Or asking how to fit a polynomial to data in general?

Comment: I believe matplotlib's `plot` function does linear interpolation, but I do not want to get into that; I want to get the `y` of the `x` as it is in the given `Line2D`, without redoing their calculations.

Comment: OK that wasn't clear from the question, I'm a bit doubtful that it at all has a value-space representation of intermediate points the closest I can think of is `line.get_path().interpolated(6).vertices[2, 1]**2` in your case.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly you want to know the height `y` of a point `p` on a line `ab`.

Assuming that the line is infinite we can do it this way.

Calculate the line slope:

```
height = lineEndY - lineStartY #calculate the line "height"
lenghtX = abs(lineStartX - lineEndX) #calculate the length of line along the X axis
slope = height / lengthX;              #calculate the "slope" by deviding length of x by height
result = x * slope;                 #calculate the x approx height on the line
```

Comment: I don't get it. What are `lineEndY`, `lineStartX`, etc?

Comment: i just wanted to demonstrate generally how you would calculate what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `numpy.interp(x, xp, fp, left=None, right=None)` can help you
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html